# Transaction in Capistrano not working

Tags: capistrano3

I have an issue with transaction in Capistrano.
The error I am getting is:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `transaction' for #<SSHKit::Backend::Netssh:0x24
08b20>
```

Capistrano version is: 3.4.0 (Rake Version: 10.4.2).
Code is as below:

```
namespace :fun do
  desc "Sample showing rescue, ensure, and on_rollback inside a transaction"
  task :stuff  do
    on roles :all do
        transaction do
            on_rollback { logger.debug "my rollback" }
                begin
                    logger.debug "main"
                    # Either run or run_locally will work the same
                    # run_locally "false"
                    run "false"
                rescue => e
                    logger.debug "rescue #{e.class}"
                    raise e
                ensure
                    logger.debug "ensure"
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Where is the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `transaction` keyword was removed in Capistrano 3.

The developers recommend using the new flow control to handle this case: https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/issues/860

Comment: thank you very much. great info:) but what will happen if a task fails? i mean all tasks will be roll-backed? as in transaction all tasks work as one transaction if one task fails, all whole transaction stops and all executed tasks are rollback. so how will it work in new flow. thanks again.

Comment: also is it possible to create a datetime global variable, please check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34645995/date-time-directory-name-global-variable-in-capistrano. thanks

Comment: If a particular task fails, the entire deploy simply stops. If the change of the current symlink hasn't happened yet, this should be fine. If that has happened, then you would want to run deploy:rollback to go back to the previous release. You can create tasks which hook into the deploy:rollback flow to make sure that reverting things works correctly. Ideally, a minimum of global system state is changed in the initial deploy, so rollback is simple.